# iOS 9 Automatic Downloading

Tags: iphone, ios

If iOS 9 automatically downloads (I know it doesn't automatically install, but it does automatically download) on an iPhone with iOS 8, and I delete the update file from the Settings app, will iOS 9 redownload automatically?

Comment: Duplicate of http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/208712/is-there-any-way-to-block-automatic-ios-updates/208751#208751 but has no upvotes so I can't flag to close

Answer (score -1):

Yes it will download automatically if you don't disable it manually.

To turn off automatic download you need to go to your settings then to the App Store and iTunes Store settings and turn it off :

[image]

Comment: Does this turn off automatic OS updates? Or does it just turn off automatic app updates?

Comment: automatic download for os update and app update